# Why does this sentence have the word "...again...": "The world's largest Eagle, stellar sea eagle, a third as big again as a golden

Tags: sentence-structure, usage

**"The world's largest Eagle, stellar sea eagle, a third as big again as a golden."** [BBC-SEA EAGLE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZiRr57HU5w8) (see:1:53-1:58)

I got confused by this sentence. As far as I understand, the sentence means "a stellar sea eagle is bigger than a golden eagle and this bigness is an amount which is one third of the size of golden?

But then why is there the word **"again"** in that sentence? Why is it not  **"...a third as big as ..."** but **"...a third as big again as ....."**?

Comment: What do you think "The world's largest Eagle, stellar sea eagle, a third as big as a golden eagle" would mean? Do you see why "again" is necessary?

Comment: @Stuart, I had no idea what it meant which is why I asked. I thought it might mean A is one third bigger than the size of B, but I was not sure if I was correct. Before coming across this sentence, I had never seen the word "again" being used in structures "as+ajdective+as". If I needed to say it, I would probably say "...A is 1,3 times the size of B....". I would never imagine including the word "again". In other words, I did not even know such a structure existed to say the same thing. But I now learnt it and I am happy. thanks for your insterest anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's [Steller's sea eagle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steller%27s_sea_eagle) (there are errors in the subtitling) and, yes, 'golden' means a golden eagle (the kind best known to British viewers).

If A is 'half as big again' as B, it is the size of B *plus* half that size. So a twelve-foot snake is half as long again as an eight-foot one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I corrected the link. It works now.

Comment: Yes, there are errors in the subtitles - the notes say that the island is called Talan, but the subtitle says Tallinn, like the capital of Estonia!

Comment: @Ok, so, "A is half as big again as B" means A is 1,5 times bigger than B. And in our case, "..a third as big again as a golden. " would mean A is 1.3 times bigger than B. Is that right?

Comment: @yunus without 'again' the sentence would mean that the sea eagle is only one third the size of the golden eagle.

Answer (score 1):

As you supposed in one of your comments, “a third again the size” does indeed mean 133% the size. In fact, I think that this numeric representation helps clarify very neatly the meaning. The *a third* is (no surprise) the 33% (okay, 33.3333…%), and the *again* means “on top of the original,” so it’s the 100%. Thus, taken together, “a third again” means

33% + 100%,

which, of course, equals 133% (also known as 1⅓).

Comment: Your explanation is right. But unfortunately, _a third again the size_ is not English, (or at least not any variety of English that I recognise). The expression is _(quantity) as (adjective) again_ or _(quantity) again as (adjective)_, except that where I have written "adjective" it could also be an adverb or quantifier: "big", "long", "high", "much", "many", "expensive", but not an abstract noun such as "size".